# Find NFD-encoded filenames

Tags: linux, file-management, rsync, encoding, filenames

I have rsync'd a directory from a Mac to a linux box containing files and folders with special characters (umlauts). Unfortunately, the Mac uses NFD encoding (thanks, Apple!) which rsync didn't convert to the NFC standard file name encoding. `rsync` lists those files as e.g. `Einversta?\#210ndniserkla?\#210rung.pdf` what should be `Einverständniserklärung.pdf` during transfer. On the linux box, that leads to duplicate files, e.g. the folder containing two files of the same name `Einverständniserklärung.pdf` (one in NFD and one in NFC encoding).

How can I find all files in NFD-encoding and delete them? This must be possible, e.g. by using `find`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

- As asked: Try to convert the file name to NFD, and see if you get the same output as input. If you do, the file name is already NFD.
- More useful: Try to convert the file name to *NFC*, and see if you get the same result. If you don't, the file name is either NFD or NFKC or NFKD or something mixed/malformed, but still not quite NFC.

To find and rename affected files, use *convmv*:

```
convmv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 --nfc ...
```

For something more easily scriptable you can use Perl's [Unicode::Normalize](https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/Normalize.html):

```
find -type f | perl -C -MUnicode::Normalize -n -e'print if $_ eq NFD($_)'
```

To find all non-NFC names (including NFD and not-normalized):

```
find -type f | perl -C -MUnicode::Normalize -n -e'print if $_ ne NFC($_)'
```